# <output> vs <ul> in displaying list items

Tags: html

I know that `<ul>` is the common tag used to display `<li>` item, but when i read [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/), it shows how the `<output>` tag also can be used to display the `<li>` item.

Currently in my project, i'm using `<output>` tag to display list items instead of `<ul>`, and i want to know if that is a wrong thing to do? I've read the `<output>` description, and i understood that `<output>` tag was supposed to display mathematical result, yet it can be used to display list, as shown in the link above.

I worried that my approach of using `<output>` to display list is wrong, though the result i got from it is just the way i want it to be.. can someone enlighten me the the difference between `<output>` and `<ul>` in terms of displaying a list items on page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you linked outputs the following:

```
<output id="list">
    <ul>
        <li>Something</li>
    </ul>
</output>
```

The `li` are not direct children of the `output` element, which is where I think you may be getting confused.

The `output` element is merely meant for outputting the result of a form action (calculation, or in the case of the example you linked, a file upload).

On [whatwg.org](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-button-element.html#the-output-element) there is no mention of the `output` element being a list, so if you're going to be trying to output `li` eleemnts to it, make sure they're going inside a `ul`.

Comment: Ah now i read again, i didn't see the ul tag encapsulates the output.join(''). But funny is, i followed the same approach as shown in that site, without the ul tag, and it still show the list properly.

Comment: Here's how it look in my project [link](http://i.imgur.com/gtLrOiN.png) .. it doesn't have any ul tag within the output tag, yet the result is still fine.

Comment: Your browser is making some assumptions, so though it looks "fine", it's not correct. An `li` is an `li` wherever it appears, this is mostly because browsers take most of the guess work away from us and make things work.

Answer (score 1):

the `<li>` elements can be included anywhere, `<output>` and `<ul>` are just tags that are used to designate areas of the page used for various forms of content.  In general, if it's a list, use a list with `<ul>` or `<ol>`.

Note: `<output>` is used for automatic calculations and would behave strangely in a `<form>`.

Comment: `<li>` elements can't be included *anywhere*.

Comment: What do you mean by behaving strangely in form? Mind elaborate that one? Because i have one output tag within the form tag on my project to display result in list-item, and somehow it causes the page to break whenever i tried to add new item into the list.

Answer (score 1):

**For `<output>`**

It shows the results of the calculation

```
<form oninput="result.value=parseInt(a.value)+parseInt(b.value)">
    0<input type="range" name="b" value="50" />100 +
    <input type="number" name="a" value="10" /> =
    <output name="result"></output>
</form>
```

**While in `<ul>`**

It is unordered list and it shows the list in unordered form i.e in meaningless form

```
<ul>
  <li>first item</li>
  <li>second item      <!-- Look, the closing </li> tag is not placed here! -->
    <ol>
      <li>second item first subitem</li>
      <li>second item second subitem</li>
      <li>second item third subitem</li>
    </ol>
  </li>                
  <li>third item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a misunderstanding. The proposed [`output` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-output-element) in HTML drafts allows phrase content (text-level content) only, so it cannot contain a `li` element or a `ul` element, even syntactically.